# federation sql view azure

Tags: sql, azure, ssms, federation

So I've been trying to use federations in SQL Azure for my site. 
I've been first trying to find a tool where i can test my coding with a full graphic interface. 
I'm unable to find the context menu for edit top 200 rows in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

There may not be exactly GUI interface to play completely with SQL Database federation through SSMS R2 however combining proper queries together with SSMS you may be able to get the results you are looking for. I am not sure how you are trying to display first 200 records with your federated data however if you provide more steps how do you do it, I may add more info.

FYI, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh778416.aspx) is how SSMS is used to work with SQL Database Federation.

Comment: Hi Avkash thanks for the reply. Am just trying to edit data in a table which is pretty small and i know that i can use queries to get the data out. But SSMS 2008 had the open table option that has been changed to Edit top 200 rows in SSMS 2012. But that context menu option is missing for me. Could this be a bug in SSMS 2012?